# Почему не делает анимацию?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Transition** и **min-width**. 
 Я делала анимацию для ширины, но почему-то она не срабатывает для min-width и min-height.

```css
.btn {
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px;

    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none ;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #DB2512;
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}

.btn:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Кнопка</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="btn">Кнопка</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для создания анимации увеличения/уменьшения объектов обычно используют CSS-свойства:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2); //к примеру 1.2
  transform: scale(1.2);
```

[Пример использования такого подхода](https://idg.net.ua/blog/devyat-prostyh-primerov-css3-perehodov)

Comment: Блок из-за этого может вылезти за экран, плюс к тому увеличенные размеры через `scale` не учитывается в %-ой ширине/высоте (Пример: `width: 50%`).

Comment: Кстати комментарии в CSS ставятся только такие: `/* к примеру 1.2 */` :)

Answer (score 0):

А зачем писать `min-width` и `min-height`? :)

```css
.btn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none ;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #DB2512;
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}

.btn:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Кнопка</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="btn">Кнопка</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Хотела бы разобраться почему не работает min-h и min-w с transition. Это код просто для примера.

Comment: @telepuz всё просто - `max-width` не `width`, также с `height`, если вы хотите оставить `min-height` и `min-width` то просто также добавьте их, но только к ним добавьте ещё `width` и `height` (с теми же значениями).